# How to create a thread check a variable in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to create a thread check a variable, I want it runs until this variable get the results I want. I wonder if you could help me?

Comment: Please check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Here you can create a thread that will show a progress bar when you are getting the result. Please let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Your question is vague, please describe what you're trying to achieve with detail. Do you want the thread to be synchronous or asynchronous? what do you want the thread to achieve?  for what purpose?

Comment: Thanks you, I will provide more details in the next questions